# How to download csv file in google trends using python requests?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, selenium, python-requests, urllib

i have the below set of python 3.5 codes:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
import requests 

company_code = '%2Fm%2F07gyp7'
company_code_unquoted = unquote(company_code)
search_params = {'gprop' : 'news' , 'q' : company_code_unquoted}

root_url = 'https://www.google.com/trends/explore'
request_link = requests.get(root_url , params = search_params)
company_spec_url = request_link.url
```

This will just go to google trends webpage for Mcdonald's. I want to download the csv file for the trends in this xpath:

```
CSV_file_xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/md-content/div/div/div[1]/trends-widget/ng-include/widget/div/div/div[1]/widget-actions/div/button[3]/div"
```

is there a way, without using selenium?

Comment: The token is dynamically generated so you won't be doing it without Js

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
target_url = "https://www.google.com/trends/api/widgetdata/relatedsearches/csv?req={"restriction":{"geo":{},"time":"2011-09-22 2016-09-22","complexKeywordsRestriction":{"keyword":[{"type":"ENTITY","value":"/m/07gyp7"}]}},"keywordType":"QUERY","metric":["TOP","RISING"],"trendinessSettings":{"compareTime":"2006-09-20 2011-09-21"},"requestOptions":{"property":"","backend":"IZG","category":0},"language":"en"}&token=APP6_UEAAAAAV-TCqKauAaqofeqB8mprsxrUMYubV1Dd&tz=-180"
with open('C:/path/to/file/to/save/report.csv', 'wb') as my_csv:
    my_csv.write(requests.get(url).content)
```

Comment: Yup, that will work,(forgot to mention) but i am trying to have it as generic and the token at the end of the target url varies.

Comment: you can concatenate base `URL` with generated part... Can you handle generated part?

Comment: I really dont know yet, how to deal with the generated part of the url.